# Ubuntu 20.04 wifi connected but no internet

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, dell

So sometimes when I'm using my computer (Dell xps 13 7390 Ubuntu 20.04) my internet connection will be lost but the wifi symbol on the top bar still stays the same and says I'm connected.

One time when this happened I tried to execute `ping google.com` and it gave me back `Temporary failure in name resolution`.

However this issue becomes resolved whenever I turn airplaine mode on and then off.

I looked into it and changed the wifi power saving value from 3 to 2 in `etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

I'm wondering if anybody has any tips. Also the following is the output of `lshw -C network`

```
     *-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 1a
   serial: 4c:1d:96:4a:7f:13
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-47-generic firmware=48.4fa0041f.0 ip=192.168.0.17 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:18 memory:9e200000-9e203fff
```

**Edit:** The wifi also fixes itself whenever I just click the name of the network I'm already connected to in the wifi settings

**Edit #2:** `nmcli m` did not output anything when the internet went offline. The output of dmesg is here https://pastebin.com/BDVuNM3R. Also note that when I run `nmcli d connect wlp2s0` then it reconnects and all is fine. I'm guessing a crude solution would be to just run that command every couple of seconds or so.

Answer (score 0):

Finding lots of other folk with the same/similar issues with the AX200. Most are focusing on drivers.

Search Askubuntu for "iwlwifi modprobe ax200".  Lots of stuff to try...

And let's move comments to chat - getting out of hand.

Comment: How do you use IPv4 address initially? Also could you explain what you mean by pinging the gateways,dns server(s), and something outside the cloud?

Comment: @Geralt - for instance: "ping 216.58.217.46" instead of "ping google.com".  This way you are not using your DNS services (which might turn out to be your issue) out of the test.
To get your gateway/dns servers IPv4 addresses try: nmcli device show | grep IP4

Comment: Hi @Frobozz. My wifi disconnected for a bit and when I tried doing "ping 216.58.217.46" I got "Destination Host Unreachable". Also I tried pinging my gateway and it also led to "Destination Host Unreachable"

Comment: Good catch!  Looks like the problem is close to home.  Let's see if we can get some more clues: try comparing "nmcli g" and "nmcli d" connected/disconnected.

Comment: Am I suppose to run those 2 commands when my wifi says connected but isn't working? Or can I run them when my wifi is working fine?

Comment: Because right now when my wifi is working fine running "nmcli g" says that everything is good i.e state is connected, connectivity is full and everything is enabled. However, when running "nmcli d" I get that device "p2p-dev-wlp2s0" which is of type "wifi-p2p" is disconnected and device "lo" which is type "loopback" is in state "unmanaged"

Comment: Also @Frobozz when the wifi is disconnected the results of "nmcli g" and "nmcli d" are the same

Comment: I updated my findings in Edit #2

Comment: You had "nmcli m" already running when you went off-line and it showed nothing?  Wow - unexpected.

Comment: Yeah I had it running before I went offline and when I went offline it didn't say anything. I'm thinking about writing a script that pings google and when it fails to run nmcli d connect wlp2s0 and go back to ping google. Or alternatively just run nmcli d connect wlp2s0 every couple of seconds. Although this does seem like more of a hack than a fix but it is what is is.

Comment: Have you experienced this disconnect on multiple hotspots?  It would be nice if we could be confident the problem is indeed on the laptop itself.

Comment: When you say hotspots do you mean different internet connections? If so, I don't really know since my laptop is only connected to a single internet connection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112973/discussion-between-frobozz-and-geralt).